# How to set a select option dropdown from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, local-storage

I have a select option dropdown with a default set that has no value, is disabled, and set as selected. The first time a person runs through the form they pick their selection. The selection is saved to local storage. They run through some questions then are reverted back to that initial form where all types input values set to hold the values saved in localStorage. However, I am having trouble setting the select option dropdown to the value that was saved in the local storage. I also have a button that allows the person to clear the session, thus reseting all the form fields. Below is a sample of the code.

HTML:

```
<select id="gender" name="gender" required="" aria-required="true">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your gender</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
<label>Gender</label>
```

JavaScript to save selected value to local storage:

```
 var gender = document.getElementById("gender");
 localStorage.setItem('gender', gender.options[gender.selectedIndex].value);
```

JavaScript to set select option dropdown once the value is already saved, where the problem is:

```
document.getElementById("gender").value = localStorage.getItem('gender');
// Or this one, neither seem to work
$("#gender").val(localStorage.getItem("gender"));
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

**Update: After looking a little further, I just found that it is changing the value of the first option from "" to "Male" instead of selecting the option that has Male set as its value. But I still can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Does straight up `$("#gender").val("Female");` work? Try setting `gender.selectedIndex`, you'll need to add a lookup to convert the value into an index.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ec4pkoer/ Are you getting errors in your browser console?

Comment: @halcyon: It does not.

Comment: @ParkerWilliams try removing `disabled` from the 0th option. Maybe that's blocking it?

Comment: @ChrisG: No errors in the console. And on the save, the default goes back to the first option "Choose your gender", then when you click load, it should reshow the chosen gender from the localStorage.

Comment: @Halcyon: Removing disabled didn't work either. I need the disabled there as I don't want users to have that as an option to pick.

Comment: Do you maybe have another element on the page with id `gender`?

Comment: @Halcyon: Just rechecked and I do not. Only the one.

Comment: It must be something on the page. See if you can remove anything that might interfere. As Chris demonstrates it works when you run it separately.